# In POI, how to rename a sheet without changing references to it?

Tags: reference, apache-poi, formula, renaming

I have SheetA, that SheetX has formula references to.
Now I want to replace SheetA by SheetB which is similar (but has additional rows).
To do that I rename SheetA to OldSheetA, then rename SheetB to SheetA.

This did not work because formula references on SheetX now point to OldSheetA instead of SheetA:

```
='SheetA'!G5  --becomes--> ='OldSheetA'!G5
```

How could I keep references pointing to SheetA ?

Comment: Sorry that part was confusing so I removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a solution using POI but this simple formula fix does the trick. Use INDIRECT() function in formulas to refer to SheetA so that they will not be affected by sheet renaming.

Instead of formula like this:

```
=SheetA!B2
```

Change to this:

```
=INDIRECT("SheetA!B2")
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to keep references pointing to SheetA is to avoid renaming it.

I suspect that the only choices you will have are:

1. To repoint your references in SheetX after all the renaming is done.
   -or-
2. To copy your data from SheetA to a new sheet, then create SheetB's data in place on SheetA

Comment: thanks @jmarkmurphy. My workbook is SXSSF (streaming-model workbook) and so I cannot overwrite current content of the sheets. I found a solution by using INDIRECT() function in the formulas. For example, change formula, =SWIBHist!B2 to =INDIRECT("SWIBHist!B2").